# Dulong-petit's high temperature heat capacity limit

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

As per Dulong-petits rule almost all substance has a higher heat capacity limit, approximately C= 24.94 J/molK. [solids C=Cp=Cv]

But there are many substances(salts like Agcl,Cucl etc) whose heat capacity(Cp) go well beyond that limit with increase in temperature as the substance reaches the melting point.

Is there any law/rule that describes, why there increase in heat capacity(Cp) with temperature? 
Is there a maximum temperature limit for Dulong petits rule?
Is significant thermal expansion in solids beyond certain temperature is the cause of increase in heat capacity?

Kindly suggest a paper/book that address this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Dulong & Petit value can be derived from the number of degrees of freedom per atom. A degree of freedom is a quadratic term in energy: kinetic energy is proportional to $v^2$. Potential energy is proportional to $\Delta x^2$ in the harmonic approximation.

Which is what points to the reason why real values of $c_v$ are higher: anharmonic terms in the potential surfaces. Thermal expansion also shows that there must be such terms.

A second reason is vacancy formation. There is an activation energy for that, so that gives a contribution that increases exponentially with temperature.

I suppose this is in Ashcroft & Mermin? Or in Kittel?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am new to solid state physics, I will look into those books.